# Como usar un alias en un where SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, where, sql-server-management

Mi duda es como puedo utilizar el alias que le doy a una columna en un where, es decir si tengo esta consulta

```
select name as 'Nombre Estudiante',
c1 as 'Calificacion 1',
c2 as 'Calificacion 2',
c3 as 'Calificacion 3',
tel as 'Telefono',
mun as 'Municipio',
case when (c1+c2+c3)/3 >= 5 
        then 'APROBADO'
        else 'SUSPENSO'
        End as Resultado
from Alumnos
```

y quiero hacer un where de la nueva columna que agregue, es decir de 'Resultado', como puedo usar el alias de 'Resultado' en la clausula where? Porque si intento agregar la clausula de esta manera no me trae nada la consulta

> where 'Resultado' = 'Aprobado'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La respuesta directa es **no se puede**, sin embargo hay varias cosas que puedes hacer para lograrlo.

La que a mi más me gusta, es convertir esta consulta en un CTE, de manera que puedas referenciar por su nombre a todas las columnas, incluyendo las que tienen cálculos complejos. Por ejemplo:

```
with
Calificacion as (
select   name as [Nombre Estudiante]
       , c1 as [Calificacion 1]
       , c2 as [Calificacion 2]
       , c3 as [Calificacion 3]
       , tel as Telefono
       , mun as Municipio,
       , case when (c1+c2+c3)/3 >= 5 
           then 'APROBADO'
           else 'SUSPENSO'
         end as Resultado
from Alumnos
)
select *
  from Calificacion
 where Resultado <> 'SUSPENSO'
    or [Calificacion 3] > 7;
```

Si observas,tu query original está *envuelto* en la sintaxis:

```
with
NombreDelCTE (
  TuQuery
)
```

Después del último paréntesis, puedes escribir un query dónde invocas a tu consulta anterior en la cláusula `from` por el nombre que le das al CTE. A este nivel, ya no hay visibilidad de nada *interno* de la consulta, solamente el resultado como si se tratara de una vista creada *al vuelo*.

Puedes crear tantas de estas *vistas* como necesites de manera consecutiva, así:

```
with
NombreDelPrimerCTE (
  PrimeraConsulta
)
, NombreDelSegundoCTE (
  SegundaConsulta
)
, NombreDelTercerCTE (
  TerceraConsulta
)
select...
```

Una de las características que me parecen más interesantes es que en el segundo CTE puedes invocar al primero en la cláusula from... y así, a medida que avanzas, tus nuevas consultas tienen visibilidad de las que se han ido creando antes en la sentencia. En mi opinión, esto permite construir en una sola consulta respuestas que llevan varios pasos para realizar cálculos complejos o que contienen condiciones con lógica compleja.

Comment: Solo una pregunta, la consulta que haga debe traer solo una fila como resultado? dado que intente con la subconsulta y me salio un error que decia 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'

Comment: La respuesta no menciona subconsultas.

Comment: @Leinad como dice Luis, mi respuesta no incluye sub-consultas y tu consulta puede devolver cualquier número de filas, eso no es ningún problema. El mensaje que estás obteniendo es por otro problema, que igual tendrías aunque no uses CTE's.

Answer (score 3):

Para eso tendrías que convertir la consulta actual en una subconsulta:

```
select 
  * 
from 
  (
    select 
      name as 'Nombre Estudiante', 
      c1 as 'Calificacion 1', 
      c2 as 'Calificacion 2', 
      c3 as 'Calificacion 3', 
      tel as 'Telefono', 
      mun as 'Municipio', 
      case when (c1 + c2 + c3)/ 3 >= 5 then 'APROBADO' else 'SUSPENSO' End as Resultado 
    from 
      Alumnos
  ) t 
where 
  Resultado = 'APROBADO'
```

Comment: Una pregunta, el 't' despues de cerrar la subconsulta para que es?

Comment: 't' es el alias de la subconsulta. Se puede usar así tal cual o con las expresión `AS t` , el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: Te recomiendo que revises la otra respuesta. Esta es correcta, pero la otra ofrece mayor funcionalidad para operaciones más complejas.